# Can't connect to an EC2 Amazon Linux MASE Desktop via RDP (error loading libvnc.so)

Tags: amazon-ec2

Spun up an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance with .NET 6, PowerShell, Mono, and MATE Desktop Environment within EC2. I'm attempting to connect to it via RDP on my Mac M1 Pro workstation but I cannot connect. Every time I attempt to connect I get this error:

"Error loading libvnc.so specified in xdrp.ini, please add a valid entry like lib=libxrdp-vnc.so or similar".

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Connected via ssh and performed a sudo yum update to make sure all binaries are up to date and then rebooted.
- Checked that: xrdp-0.9.22-3.el7.x86_64 installed. It's my understanding there was a bug that was fixed and was supposed to fix the issue (https://salsa.debian.org/debian-remote-team/xrdp/-/merge_requests/5).
- Searched about 100+ articles which included some of these:

  - https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2689
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session
    -https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/13k1bci/xrdp_error/

According to the post here: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/xrdp-fails-to-load-libvnc-so-and-refuses-to-start/82672/3 there is an issue with 9.22.3 where the libvnc.so package is missing. Confirmed by looking at the /usr/lib64/xrdp directory. I upgraded xrdp manually via RPM to 9.22.4 and I see that the libvnc.so library is now there however; now when I login I get yet another missing library error that I am now missing "libxup.so".

"Error loading libxup.so specified in xdrp.ini, please add a valid entry like lib=libxrdp-vnc.so or similar".

I also tried updating the xvnc path in xrdp.ini to use the specific path to no avail.

```html
[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=/usr/lib64/xrdp/libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

I checked inside of /usr/lib64/xrdp/ and I see that missing libxup.so library is in fact there..

```
[root@ip-172-31-4-19 xrdp]# ls
libcommon.so.0  libcommon.so.0.0.0  libmc.so  libscp.so.0  libscp.so.0.0.0  libvnc.so  libxrdpapi.so.0  libxrdpapi.so.0.0.0  libxrdp.so.0  libxrdp.so.0.0.0  libxup.so
```

Completely lost. How do I do a simple RDP connection to this host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this *exact* issue and happened upon this post in my search for answers; I've since solved the problem and can RDP in, though it looks like you have performed the same steps as I.

If you are still facing this problem, see below for my shell history.

```
[ec2-user@ip-addr ~]$ history
    1  sudo yum update
    2  sudo reboot
    3  sudo passwd ec2-user
    4  sudo openssl req -x509 -sha384 -newkey rsa:3072 -nodes -keyout /etc/xrdp/key.pem -out /etc/xrdp/cert.pem -days 365
    5  sudo systemctl enable xrdp
    6  sudo systemctl start xrdp
    7  cd /etc/xrdp
    8  ls
    9  cat xrdp.ini
   10  vim xrdp.ini
   11  sudo vim xrdp.ini
   12  wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/testing/7/x86_64/Packages/x/xrdp-0.9.22-4.el7.x86_64.rpm # DID NOT WORK
   13  ping 8.8.8.8
   14  wget google.com
   15  ls
   16  cdf # fatfingered
   17  cd
   18  wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/testing/7/x86_64/Packages/x/xrdp-0.9.22-4.el7.x86_64.rpm # If at first you do not succeed, try and try again
   19  wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/xrdp/0.9.22/4.el7/x86_64/xrdp-0.9.22-4.el7.x86_64.rpm # <<-- WORKED
   20  sudo yum install ./xrdp-0.9.22-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
   21  sudo reboot now
```

Here is the pertinent section of the working `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`:

```ini
[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
#lib=libxrdp-vnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

Comment: OMG it's a miracle. For me, step 19 was the missing link. The package I downloaded clearly still had the issue. Once I performed step 19-21, I was good to go. Thanks for fighting the good fight and figuring this out. Hopefully folks will bump into this thread and finally have an answer!

Comment: It soothes my soul to have made your day a little better  I'm glad you have a resolution to an incredibly frustrating issue. Have a great week, Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it only worked with the below package, the newer releases would fail to install due to Amazon OpenSSL lib dependencies.

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/xrdp/0.9.22/4.el8/x86_64/xrdp-0.9.22-4.el8.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum install xrdp-0.9.22-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the exact same issue with Amazon Linux2 Instance with Mate GUI. Below steps resolved the issue for me.

```
wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/testing/7/x86_64/Packages/x/xrdp-0.9.22.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install ./xrdp-0.9.22.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo reboot
```